# How to provide custom linker flags to a particular target while building chromium through GN?

Tags: git, build, chromium

I am trying to build latest chromium (cef) on my local machine. I have been successful in building it through automate-git.py using the GN framework. However, I also need to provide some extra linker flags to a specific target (libcef).

I believe this is to be done through changes in args.gn file while creating a new build directory. But, I could not get sufficient documentation regarding how exactly to provide linker flags to a specific target in GN.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

About chromium build configurations, you can reference the following links:

1. Build Instructions (Android)
   https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/android-build-instructions
2. The guide of gn build system
   https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/tools/gn/docs/quick_start.md
3. About the link flags, you can reference: ldflags
   https://codereview.chromium.org/1887303003/diff/20001/build/config/compiler/BUILD.gn

   ```
   ldflags += [
     "-fPIC",
     "-Wl,-z,noexecstack",
     "-Wl,-z,now",
     "-Wl,-z,relro",
   ]
   if (!using_sanitizer) {
     if (!use_cfi_diag) {
       ldflags += [ "-Wl,-z,defs" ]
     }

     # Functions interposed by the sanitizers can make ld think
     # that some libraries aren't needed when they actually are,
     # http://crbug.com/234010. As workaround, disable --as-needed.
     if (!is_nacl && !is_android) {
       # TODO(pcc): Fix linker bug which requires us to link pthread
       # unconditionally here (crbug.com/623236).
       ldflags += [
         "-Wl,--no-as-needed",
         "-lpthread",
       ]
     }
     ldflags += [ "-Wl,--as-needed" ]
   }
   ```

   }